# Are doppelgangers neuter?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons

Because of their shapechanging ability, I was wondering if Doppelgangers have a sex or are they sexless? Are they male, female or neither?

Does it differ between editions of D&d?

Comment: Two doting doppelgangers? xD

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is defined in some settings, such as Eberron where they are neuter:

> Unlike true doppelgangers, changelings do have gender in their natural form, although they can adopt any shape they like. - *Changelings*, p. 12, *Eberron Campaign Setting*

It is not otherwise/explicitly defined in the Monster Manual for other settings. If it's a plot point, the GM should decide.

Answer (score 10):

The only official source I can find for this question is an article published in Dragon #80 entitled "The Psychology of Doppelgangers", which includes the following conversation:

> "My  lord,  you  don't  understand.  One  of
>   the  anomalies  I  found  was  the  absence  of
>   any  reproductive  organs,  either  on  the  dead
>   specimen  or  this  one.  This  has  to  mean-"
>
> "You're  quite  clever,  wizard."  This  time,
>   the hissing voice was slightly less contemptuous.
>   "No,  we  cannot  reproduce  except  in
>   your  form."

So apparently, at least in previous editions, doppelgangers are sexless and rely on taking human form to perpetuate their species.

Comment: the current version of the question doesn't mention D&D 3.5e at all, so you might want to update this answer

Comment: @doppelgreener Oh yeah, good point.